# Is there a way to group a selectors in SASS?

Tags: html, css, sass, bootstrap-4

For example, if I had some links, and I wanted to make some links green and red when hovered on or clicked.

Instead of doing:

```css
.links a {
 color: green;
}

.links a:visited {
 color: green;
}

.links a:hover {
 color: red;
}

.links a:active {
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="links">
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
</div>
```

What could I do?

I tried using
`.links a:hover, a:active{}` and `.links a,a:visited{}`
however that resulted in other links using the color in this rule.

If this is relevant, I am using bootstrap 4 with sass.

Comment: You forgot the class in the subsequent selectors in your list.

Comment: In plain CSS you can separate selectors with a comma, so `.links a:hover, .links a:active { color: red; }` — using SASS you can _nest_ selectors; see Berk Kurkcuoglu's answer.

Comment: Protip: CSS selectors are not tags. Nor are DOM elements. Tags are bits of text in your markup file which start and end with angle brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe with SASS(unlike SCSS)  It would be

```
.links   
  & a, a:visited 
    color: green 
  & a:hover, a.active
    color: red
```

producing once compiled :

```
.links a, .links a:visited {
  color: green;
}
.links a:hover, .links a.active {
  color: red;
}
```

SCSS version

```
.links {
  & a, a:visited {
    color: green;
  }
  & a:hover,  a.active {
    color: red;
  }
}
```